# Do iPhoto and Picasa let me view photos at a 1:1 pixel ratio?

Tags: picasa, iphoto

I need to compare photos at a 1:1 pixel ratio (not downscaled to fit the monitor). For this, I need to set the view to 1:1 and then go through the photos using the arrow keys. As you can guess, I need the view setting to remain at 1:1 until I reset it, as with Lightroom.

Do iPhoto 11 and Picasa 3.9 on the Mac let me do this?

EDIT 1: This is not a Retina display. It's a 30-inch monitor at 2560 x 1600. And if I'm using a Retina display, I'd still expect the 1:1 to refer to physical pixels, no matter the pixel density. In other words, if I have a 2880 x 1800 photo, it should exactly fit the screen.

EDIT 2: To answer the question of why I am doing this, I am comparing cameras (iPhone vs NEX vs a superzoom) so that I understand exactly what the limitations of each camera are, under what situations (if any) I can leave the dedicated cameras at home and just use the iPhone, or if the superzoom gives me photo quality indistinguishable from the NEX.

EDIT 3: More information about why I'm doing this: The immediate goal is to help me decide under what circumstances the iPhone and the superzoom produce photos as good as the NEX.

This should help me decide when I can leave the other camera(s) at home and use the iPhone. Or whether I buying the aforementioned superzoom camera makes more sense for me than buying one or more zoom lenses for the NEX (each of which is as expensive as the superzoom camera).

I do not print out my photos. I view them full-screen on my monitor. So, if two cameras produce equivalent results when the photos are viewed full-screen, then I can buy the cheaper / smaller / lighter / more flexible option (like a superzoom camera instead of a zoom lens for the NEX).

The catch is that the best monitor I have today is 2560 x 1600, but I can imagine buying a [5120 x 2880 monitor](http://www.macrumors.com/2013/06/10/apple-posts-27-retina-imac-sized-os-x-mavericks-background/). So, I don't want to choose a camera now and then realize later this year or the next year when I upgrade my monitor that my photos are not particularly good.

So, I want to compare cameras at 5120 x 2880. But my cameras take photos at a lower resolution, which is 4912 x 3264 for the NEX, and 3264 x 2448. So, I want to compare photos at 1:1 display.

(In an ideal world, if all my cameras shot at higher than 5120 x 2880, I would downscale all the images to this resolution and then compare them at 1:1. But since my cameras shoot at lower resolution, I want to compare them at 1:1. I don't want to upscale, since that reduces quality.)

Please let me know if this reasoning has a flaw. Thanks.

Comment: To answer your last question (whether two images from different cameras have equivalent image quality), you should compare the photos at the same *overall* size, not at pixel-level detail.

Comment: And, I'd like to hear more about *why* you answered the retina display question in that way. I agree that expecting the 1:1 correspondence to remain would be *reasonable* (although it turns out to not be the case in applications that don't ask for special handling), but the important question is: why do you think that adds special value in comparing images?

Comment: I realize that I'm being a bit difficult, and I have no idea what the basic answer your simple software question even is since I don't use those programs, but I think this *is* really important overall. See [this question about high-density displays](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30358/is-it-better-to-edit-photos-with-a-high-pixel-per-inch-monitor). I know you don't have one, but it is still relevant because the basic premise is examined in the answers.

Comment: mattdm, you're not being difficult at all. On the contrary, you're forcing me to examine my assumptions, which is good. I added an "EDIT 3" to the question. Please take a look. And, yes, I will go through the question you linked. Thanks very much.

Comment: completely useless comparison. As long as they look the same at the size you're interested in, how they look when pixel peeking is utterly irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks, jwenting. The size I'm interested in is 5120 x 2880. How do you suggest I compare cameras that produce images of smaller size than this? Upscale? Or compare at 1:1?

Answer (score 1):

**iPhoto and Picasa are discontinued products.** It past time to switch to a different image viewer if you haven't already done so.

**Keeping the same zoom level while browsing photos does not appear to be possible** in both iPhoto and Picasa. However, in both programs, you can press <kbd>1</kbd> to zoom to 100%.

- Apple Support Communities: [How do I keep the zoom level on iPhoto?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6495512)
- Google Picasa Product Forum: [Photo Viewer: configurable default zoom in fullscreen ("Fit image to screen")](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/RzPUtX-AyW0)